# Singularities of representation varieties

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, low-dimensional-topology

**Background:**

Fix an algebraically closed field $k$ and a group $\mathbb{G}$ which is algebraic over $k.$

Let $H$ be a discrete group.

There is a functor from $k$-algebras to sets which sends $A \to Hom(H, \mathbb{G}(A)).$  This functor is representable.  Let $\mathcal{A}_H$ be the representative.

Then $V_H:= Spec(\mathcal{A}_H)$ is called the **representation scheme** of the group $G.$ In general, this scheme can be non-reduced and singular.

The GIT quotient $X_H:= V_H // \mathbb{G}^{ad}$ is called the **character scheme.** It is also in general non-reduced and singular.

Finally, there is an open subscheme $X_H^0 \subset X_H$ whose $k$-points consist of irreducible representations.

**My question:**

I believe that $X_H^0$ can also be singular an non-reduced. However, I don't know any examples.   I would be interested in examples with any group $H$, and any algebraic group $\mathbb{G}.$ I would particularly interested in cases where $H$ arises as the fundamental groups of a $3$-manifold.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123198/can-the-sl-2-character-variety-of-a-three-manifold-be-nonreduced

Comment: Thanks for the link!